# How can I omit points when filtering OSM data with Osmosis

Tags: openstreetmap, filter, osmosis

I am trying to get data for rivers/waterways around the world. I have downloaded the planet file from OSM (as well as a North America file from Geofabrik), and am trying to use Osmosis to filter out only the ways tagged as rivers, streams, etc. The command I am using is the following:

`osmosis --read-pbf planet-latest.osm.pbf --log-progress --tf accept-ways waterway=river,stream,canal natural=water --used-node --write-pbf planet-latest-waterways.osm.pbf`

When I run this on the North America file, it completes and results in a 2GB file. However, when loading the file in QGIS, the points take quite a while to process and if I choose not to display them, QGIS runs for a long time before displaying any lines (presumably silently iterating through and rejecting all the points). Many of the points are irrelevant (e.g. bus stops). Is there a way to not include the points using Osmosis, so that QGIS jumps straight to rendering the lines and polygons?

If I am going around this in the wrong way, please let me know! I am happy to learn new tools, I just am not sure which ones are the best for this type of job.